# How do you position the title and legend in tmap?

Tags: r, tmap

I am new to programming and am currently enrolled in an introductory spatial analysis course which uses R. The following code yields the tmaps included below. 
How can I center the title for each tmap as well as position the legend on the top right without laying over top the maps themselves?

Thank you very much for your assistance.

```
  ga1 = tm_shape(a2georgia) +
  tm_polygons('PctBlack', style='quantile', breaks=c(4.98,11.75, 22.35,27.64, 32.55, 40.06,   48.18, 79.64),
              n=8, palette=c('lightblue','khaki1', 'red3'), title='Quantiles(8)',
              border.col='grey27', alpha=.9) +
  tm_layout(legend.position = c("right", "top"), title= '% of Population of Black Race', title.position = c('right', 'top'))


ga_cartogram <- cartogram_cont(a2georgia, "PctBlack", itermax=5)

  ga2 = tm_shape(ga_cartogram) + 
  tm_polygons("PctBlack", style='quantile', breaks=c(4.98,11.75, 22.35,27.64, 32.55, 40.06, 48.18, 79.64), 
              n=8, palette=c('lightblue','khaki1', 'red3'), title='Quantiles(8)',
              border.col='grey27', alpha=.9) +
  tm_layout(legend.position = c("right", "top"), title= '% of Population of Black Race',  title.position = c('right', 'top'))


tmap_arrange(ga1,ga2)
```

[image: Tmaps]

Comment: The documentation appears to have `main.title.position` with possible value `center`. Have you looked into that?

Comment: Just tried that and the legend becomes positioned higher up but still slightly overtop the map. The main title was not affected.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that {tmap} draws legend and titles inside the bounding box of your polygon. To make more room you have to extend the bounding box somewhat.

A while back I wrote a blog post on this topic, you might want to have a look at that https://www.jla-data.net/eng/adjusting-bounding-box-of-a-tmap-map/

As your example is not exactly reproducible I will demonstrate the technique on the North Carolina shapefile that is shipped with {sf} and thus widely available.

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)

# NC counties - a shapefile shipped with the sf package
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package ="sf"))


# bad, bad map...
tm_shape(nc) + tm_polygons("NWBIR74", style='quantile', 
                           breaks=c(4.98,11.75, 22.35,27.64, 32.55, 40.06, 48.18, 79.64),
                           n=8, palette=c('lightblue','khaki1', 'red3'), 
                           title='Quantiles(8)',
                           border.col='grey27', alpha=.9) +
  tm_layout(legend.position = c("right", "top"), 
            title= '% of Population of Black Race', 
            title.position = c('right', 'top'))
```

[image]

```
# make some bbox magic
bbox_new <- st_bbox(nc) # current bounding box

xrange <- bbox_new$xmax - bbox_new$xmin # range of x values
yrange <- bbox_new$ymax - bbox_new$ymin # range of y values

# bbox_new[1] <- bbox_new[1] - (0.25 * xrange) # xmin - left
 bbox_new[3] <- bbox_new[3] + (0.25 * xrange) # xmax - right
# bbox_new[2] <- bbox_new[2] - (0.25 * yrange) # ymin - bottom
bbox_new[4] <- bbox_new[4] + (0.2 * yrange) # ymax - top

bbox_new <- bbox_new %>%  # take the bounding box ...
  st_as_sfc() # ... and make it a sf polygon

# looks better, does it?
tm_shape(nc, bbox = bbox_new) + tm_polygons("NWBIR74", style='quantile', 
                           breaks=c(4.98,11.75, 22.35,27.64, 32.55, 40.06, 48.18, 79.64),
                           n=8, palette=c('lightblue','khaki1', 'red3'), 
                           title='Quantiles(8)',
                           border.col='grey27', alpha=.9) +
  tm_layout(legend.position = c("right", "top"), 
            title= '% of Population of Black Race', 
            title.position = c('right', 'top'))
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for your response. May I ask you to clarify the following? Are you saying that a sf geometry is needed?bbox_new <- bbox_new %>%  # take the bounding box ...
  st_as_sfc() # ... and make it a sf polygon

Comment: The sf::st_as_sfc is necessary because bbox argument of tmap::tm_shape expects a geometry, while sf::st_bbox returns a vector; have a look at {sf} documentation for more detailed explanation https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sf/versions/0.8-1/topics/st_bbox